# NVD3 : nv.d3.js:14314 Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am new java script and D3, I am building some sample reports using D3, but constantly facing `"Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function"` in stackAreaChart display. I tried all my best to get rid of this error but no joy.

**Exception:**

```
nv.d3.js:14314 Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function
    at nv.d3.js:14314
    at nv.utils.state._set (nv.d3.js:1248)
    at nv.utils.state.update (nv.d3.js:1269)
    at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous> (nv.d3.js:14353)
    at d3.min.js:3
    at Y (d3.min.js:1)
    at Array.Co.each (d3.min.js:3)
    at Array.chart (nv.d3.js:14339)
    at Array.Co.call (d3.min.js:3)
    at Object.generate (main.js:250)
```

**Sample data I am sending for stackAreaChart:**

```
[{"key":"RT.Gjoa_SPS.E","values":[[1499955690000,-0.019999314282704246],[1499955
750000,0.05166495085946679],[1499955810000,-0.056664803271206064],[1499955870000
,0.08833037627180006]]},{"key":"RT.Gjoa_SPS","values":[[1499955690000,23.4658844
70517647],[1499955750000,104.52984900503316],[1499955810000,-631.4456184793839],
[1499955870000,1683.1438952034932]]},{"key":"RT.Gjoa_SPS.B","values":[[149995587
0000,0.002222081668744225]]},{"key":"RT.Gjoa_SPS.D","values":[[1499955690000,0],
[1499955750000,-0.003333234941159513],[1499955810000,0.003333234941159513],[1499
955870000,0]]}]
```

Below is my complete main.js: please check if anything i am missing or need to be handled in order to get rid of this error.

**main.js**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://HOST_IP:3000');

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// // // TimeSeries Chart
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var timeSeriesChart;
var timeSeriesChartData = [];
//function drawTimeSeriesChart()
//{
nv.addGraph(function() {
        timeSeriesChart = nv.models.lineChart().duration(750).useInteractiveGuideline(true).margin({right:40});
    timeSeriesChart.xAxis.axisLabel("Timestamp").tickFormat(function(d){ return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")(new Date(d));});    
        timeSeriesChart.yAxis.axisLabel("Stats").tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
        d3.select('#FMCChart1').append('svg').datum(timeSeriesChartData).call(timeSeriesChart);
        nv.utils.windowResize(timeSeriesChart.update());
        return timeSeriesChart;
});
//}

socket.on("timeSeriesChartData",function(timeSeriesData){
    console.log("chart updated");
    d3.select('#FMCChart1 svg')
    .datum(timeSeriesData)
    .call(timeSeriesChart);
});


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// // // Discrete Bar Chart
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var discreteChart;
var discreteChartData;
function drawDiscreteChart()
{
nv.addGraph(function() {
  discreteChart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label})    //Specify the data accessors.
      .y(function(d) { return +d.value})
      .staggerLabels(true)    //Too many bars and not enough room? Try staggering labels.
      //.tooltips(false)        //Don't show tooltips
      .showValues(true)       //...instead, show the bar value right on top of each bar.
      //.transitionDuration(350)
      ;

  d3.select('#FMCChart2 svg')
      .datum(discreteChartData)
      .call(discreteChart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(discreteChart.update);

  return discreteChart;
});
}

socket.on("discreteChartData",function(disChartData){
   discreteChartData=disChartData;
   console.log("Discrete Chart ", disChartData[0].values[0].value);
    //discreteChart.update();
    drawDiscreteChart();
});

// // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Pie Chart
// // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var pieChart;
var pieChartData;
function drawPieChart() {
//Donut chart example
nv.addGraph(function() {
pieChart = nv.models.pieChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return +d.value })
  .showLabels(true)     //Display pie labels
  .labelThreshold(.05)  //Configure the minimum slice size for labels to show up
  .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
  .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
  .donutRatio(0.35);  //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.     

  d3.select("#FMCChart3 svg")
    .datum(pieChartData)
    //.transition().duration(350)
    .call(pieChart); /// ERROR OCCURRED ON THIS LINE

 return pieChart;
});
}


socket.on("pieChartData",function(pChartData){
    pieChartData=pChartData; 
    console.log("Pie Chart: ",pChartData[0].label,pChartData[0].value);
    drawPieChart();
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Donut Chart
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var donutChart;
var donutChartData;
function drawDonutChart() {
//Donut chart example
nv.addGraph(function() {
donutChart = nv.models.pieChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return +d.value })
  .showLabels(true)     //Display pie labels
  .labelThreshold(.05)  //Configure the minimum slice size for labels to show up
  .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
  .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
  .donutRatio(0.35);  //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.     

  d3.select("#FMCChart4 svg")
    .datum(donutChartData)
    //.transition().duration(350)
    .call(donutChart); /// ERROR OCCURRED ON THIS LINE

 return donutChart;
});
}


socket.on("donutChartData",function(dChartData){
    donutChartData=dChartData; 
    console.log("Donut Chart: ",dChartData[0].label,dChartData[0].value);
    drawDonutChart();
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Alert Chart
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

socket.on('fetched-callRestAPI',function(msg){
    // console.log("warning : " + msg);
        console.log("Rest Call --- >> ",msg);
    var data = JSON.parse(msg);

    if(data.content == "true") {
        $('#flag').toggleClass("card-panel green");
    } 
    else{
        $('#flag').toggleClass("card-panel red");
    }

});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Stacked Area Chart
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var stackedAreaChart;
var stackedAreaChartData;

function drawStackedAreaChart() {
//Donut chart example
nv.addGraph(function() {
stackedAreaChart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                  .margin({right: 100})
                  .x(function(d) { return d[0] })   //We can modify the data accessor functions...
                  .y(function(d) { return d[1] })   //...in case your data is formatted differently.
                  .useInteractiveGuideline(true)    //Tooltips which show all data points. Very nice!
                  .rightAlignYAxis(true)      //Let's move the y-axis to the right side.
                  //.transitionDuration(500)
                  .showControls(true)       //Allow user to choose 'Stacked', 'Stream', 'Expanded' mode.
                  .clipEdge(true);  //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.

                  //Format x-axis labels with custom function.
    stackedAreaChart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { 
          return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) 
    });

    stackedAreaChart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  d3.select("#FMCChart5 svg")
    .datum(stackedAreaChartData)
    //.transition().duration(350)
    .call(stackedAreaChart); /// ERROR OCCURRED ON THIS LINE

 return stackedAreaChart;
});
}

socket.on("openTSDBRestAPIData",function(openTSDBData){
    stackedAreaChartData=openTSDBData;
    console.log("stackedAreaChartData: ",openTSDBData);
    drawStackedAreaChart();
});
```

Comment: Please show us the structure of `openTSDBData`.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado  I have updated question with openTSDB data sample

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle/Plunkr demonstrating the issue. In general, the process for debugging these issues is to put a debugger statement in accessor functions like .x to see what's going on. I would suggest you update drawStackedAreaChart to accept a data parameter.

Comment: I facing issues posting on JSFiddle/Plunkr

Comment: Well I can also data reaching into drawStackedAreaChart..